AI agent giving a summary of changes on Wikipedia article(s)
Which tools (software, libraries) would you recommend for creating an AI autonomous agent that is able to monitor a list of Wikipedia articles, giving me overview of what is new every 8 hours? The tool should be better than watchlist or SiteDelta Firefox extension.
For a given Wikipedia article it should give me something like
"Today the topic of X is extended by such and such sentences with reference Y"
This means, it should be readable. That's why I'm looking for AI tools.
It should work on Linux.

As a base for this, would you know a non-AI tool that gives you just a list of diffs, on a single (potentially long) page?

@NicolasRaoul It's RSS feed for changes of particular article.
